# What does "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tuple'" means?

Tags: python, scipy, integer, tuples, operands

I got a error saying:

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tuple'

How do I correct it?

```
from scipy import integrate
cpbar = lambda T: (3.826 - (3.979e-3)*T + 24.558e-6*T**2 - 22.733e-9*T**3 + 6.963e-12*T**4)*8.314
deltahbarCH4 = integrate.quad(cpbar,298,1000)
var = deltahbarCH4

hRPbar = hRPbar + (deltahbarCO2 + 2*deltahbarH2O - var -2*deltahbarO2)
```

Comment: It means that you are trying to use the subtraction operator `-` between a number and a tuple. It will be easier to debug if you tell us which line it is on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`integrate.quad()` returns a tuple](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html); `deltahbarCO2 + 2*deltahbarH2O` is an integer, you are trying to subtract the `var` tuple.

If you wanted *just* the integral `y` of the `integrate.quad()` result, use the first element of that tuple:

```
var = deltahbarCH4[0]
```

or use tuple assignment:

```
var, err = deltabarCH4
```

Answer (score 2):

That error means that you are trying to use the subtraction operator `-` between a number and a tuple.

Based on the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html), you probably want: `var = deltahbarCH4[0]`, since that will give you the actual value of the integral, which you are computing with on a later line.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tuple'

When trying to subtract **`tuple` type** from **`int` type** as shown below:

```py
    # int 
print(10 - (3,))
          # tuple
```

So, I changed **`tuple` type** to **`int` type** as shown below:

```py
print(10 - 3)
```

Then, the error above was solved:

```
7
```