# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'

Tags: tuples

c4_part1 += self.imageGrayscalePixels[xCoordinate, yCoordinate]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tuple'" means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945826/what-does-unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-tuple-means)

Comment: no my question is different

Answer (score 0):

```
self.imageGrayscalePixels[xCoordinate, yCoordinate]
```

This returns a tupel. You can't add that to an `int`. You need to extract the value from the tuple before you add it to `c4_part1`.

Example:

```
x = self.imageGrayscalePixels[xCoordinate, yCoordinate]
c4_part1 += x[0] # 0 -> index of the value
```